# Javascript: href button simulate click

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="#addnotes" onclick="javascript:submitAddNotes();">
```

How would i submit js simulated click on this ?

Comment: Can't you just run submitAddNotes()? Without simulating a click

Comment: FYI, don't prefix inline event handlers with `javascript:`. It has no use whatsoever. You could also write `onclick="asdkjfhakjhkja:submitAddNotes();"`  and it would have the same effect.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
var anchor= document.querySelector('a[href="#addnotes"');
anchor.click();
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: Is your JavaScript in the same file as your HTML or a separate file?

Comment: chrome extension scripts.js

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chrome extensions, but you might resolve it by putting it within a DOMContentLoaded event.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded